# In Angular How to detect the direct parent and communicate with it?

Tags: angular, components, parent-child, inject

I have a child component (**child.component**) which can be used in two parent components :

1. **parentA.component**
2. **parentB.component**

In this case, it's possible to make several templates like this :

```
<parentA>
  <child></child>
</parentA>

<parentA>
    <parentB>
       <child></child>
    </parentB>
</parentA>
```

For some reasons, the **child.component** need to detect if the direct parent is parentB.

I used '@Inject(forwardRef(() => parentBComponent)) private _directParent:parentBComponent'

to do this:

#### child.component.ts

```
export class ChildComponent {
     ...
     constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => parentBComponent)) private _directParent:parentBComponent){
         console.dir(_directParent);
     }
}
```

But if **child.component** is not wrapped by **parentB.component**, I get this error :

> "EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/tests/6.html:5:8 caused by: No provider for ParentBComponent!"

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

For some cases, the solution is to get the variable **_directParent** optional thanks the decorator `@Optional()` :

```
@Inject(forwardRef(() => parentBComponent)) @Optional() private _directParent:parentBComponent
```

That works if you have got only two cases and in one case there is no parentBComponent.
But **THAT DOES NOT GET THE DIRECT PARENT**, just get one parent with this component name.