# How to detect unknown direct Parent Component in Angular?

Tags: angular, annotations, parent-child, angular-decorator

I would like to find a way to detect the direct parent component in Angular 4.
It's so easy to detect child component thanks **@ViewChild** or **@ContentChildren** decorators. I didn't find the solution to do the same on the other direction.
In my case, I can have several kind of direct parent components like this :

```
<parentA-comp>
    <child-comp></child-comp>
</parentA-comp>
or...
<parentA-comp>
    <parentB-comp>
       <child-comp></child-comp>
    </parentB-comp>
</parentA-comp>
```

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031614/in-angular-how-to-detect-the-direct-parent-and-communicate-with-it) the following code can detect an ancestor component, not the direct parent component :

```
@Inject(forwardRef(() => parentBComponent)) private _directParent:parentBComponent'
```

So I have two questions :

1. Why Angular2-4 don't include @Parent decorator to make an easy way ?
   can it generates a performance matter ?
2. If there is no performance problem, how can make my own @Parent decorator to detect the direct Parent ? I tried to find a good tutorial without success.